# Proof verification (formal logic): $U = \emptyset \vdash \forall A ( U \subseteq A)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

I am doing an undergrad set theory course and I want to prove this in the context of formal logic. Please criticize my attempt of proof:

$U = \emptyset \vdash\forall A ( U \subseteq A)$

Proof:

Suppose by contradiction 
$\exists A$ such that $U \nsubseteq A$. Then:

$¬ \forall x ( x \in U \rightarrow x \in A)$

$\rightarrow$

$...$  (I want to use material implication here. How can I write properly?)

$\rightarrow$

$\exists x (x \in U)  $

Which is a contradiction.

This may look like I am cheating, because I am trying to adapt the proof of naive set theory, and that was the hint I was given..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "formal proof"?

Comment: You don't need proof by contradiction.  Once you've gotten to $$\forall x~.~\lnot x \in U \vdash \forall A \forall x ~.~ x \in U \to x \in A)$$ at that point no more set theory is needed, it is just pure first order logic.  If you are doing fitch style natural deduction, start by assuming $x \in U$.

Comment: @RuggieroRilievi He probably means "rigorous" , not "formal".

Comment: @DanielV, I probably mean that. I think I don´t actually know what formal is. Sorry.

Comment: @creepyrodent Formal means "following all the rules".  Rigorous means "absolutely reliable", as in, almost no intuition.  There are formal proofs that aren't rigorous because you might not trust the axioms.  There are rigorous proofs that aren't formal because no set of formal rules have been chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A direct proof*

What we want to prove is :

> $\forall a \ (\emptyset \subseteq a)$.

We have that $b \subseteq a$ is by definition : $\forall x (x \in b \to x \in a)$.

Thus, what we want to prove amounts to :

> $\forall a \ [\forall x \ (x \in \emptyset \to x \in a)]$.

Now, we have the [set-theory axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) : $\forall x \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$.

Now, we can "cook together the ingredients" :

1) $\forall x \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$ --- axiom

2) $\lnot (x \in \emptyset)$ --- from 1) by [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

3) $\lnot (x \in \emptyset) \to [(x \in \emptyset) \to (x \in a)]$ --- from tautology : $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$

4) $(x \in \emptyset) \to (x \in a)$ --- from 2) and 3) by [MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)

5) $\forall x \ ((x \in \emptyset) \to (x \in a))$ --- from 4) by [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

> 6) $\forall a \ [\forall x \ ((x \in \emptyset) \to (x \in a))]$ --- from 5) by UG.

---

Regarding your attempt, you have assumed $\exists a \ (\emptyset \nsubseteq a)$ that means, using again the definition of $\subseteq$ :

> $\exists a \ \exists x \ [(x \in \emptyset) \land (x \notin a)]$.

Using a double [E-elim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation), we have : $(z \in \emptyset) \land (z \notin a)$, from which :

> $(z \in \emptyset)$,

contradicting the axiom : $\forall x \ \lnot (x \in \emptyset)$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for every set $A$, i.e. that every element of $\emptyset$ is an element of $A$, for every set $A$. Let us prove that.

Let $x \in \emptyset$. By definition of $\emptyset$, such an $x$ does not exists, so we do not have anything to prove. End of the proof.

Said differently, the fact that $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for every set $A$ is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Isn´t this a naive set theory proof?

Comment: The (maybe incorrect) elementary-set-theory tag may had mislead you. I will give you an upvote then.

Comment: @creepyrodent What about this makes you think it is a "naive set theory proof"? What does "naive set theory proof" mean to you, and what would differentiate it from a "non-naive set theory proof" in your mind?

Comment: I don´t know exactly. I think it is because the proof ´´looks´´ very similar to my proof in a course where I wasn´´t aware of the existence of ZF axioms yet, which in this new course I am...